# Batch copying all metadata with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have been reencoding some old mp4 files and using ffmpeg to copy the metadata from the old files to the new ones using:

```
ffmpeg -i YDXJ0100.mp4 -i YDXJ0100_1.mp4 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy YDXJ0100_.mp4
```

Where the first file is the old version, _1 is the new one, and _.mp4 is the fixed one.

However, it is very time consuming to do it file by file.
How could I write it in a way that it does it for every old file (but not all files)?

Update:
This code works, except for the Modify data and other file timestamps:

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i "%%~nf_1.mp4" -map 1 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a "%%~nf_.mp4"
```

Comment: Operating System?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit
(64 bit was unnecessary but the comment needed more characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

batch file:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i "%%~nf_1.mp4" -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy "%%~nf_.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm!

Comment: Hm no, I correct it: weirdly, the size of the new ¨_¨ file is again the same as the original.
However, it works using the code I pasted.

Comment: OK, got it: -map 1 needed to be added:

@echo off
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i "%%~nf_1.mp4" -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy "%%~nf_.mp4"

Comment: @ragnor yeah, I'm sorry, I lost `-map 1` somewhere when tested line.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't copy Modification time.
Anyone know how to copy all metadata (handlers included if possible)?

Comment: A small update: handlers seem to work with the following:
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i "%%~nf_1.mp4" -map 1 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a "%%~nf_.mp4"

But file data are still not changed.