# Copy all FFMPEG streams and metadata except the first video stream

Tags: command-line, audio, ffmpeg, video, matroska

I have some "voice memos" that were recorded through the video camera app. They have huge video streams, but I just want the audio.

How can I copy all streams via ffmpeg except the first video stream? And how can I include all metadata too?

Related: [Batch copying all metadata with ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/1599100/batch-copying-all-metadata-with-ffmpeg)

[Copy all metadata (file and video) and non-video streams from one video to another](https://superuser.com/questions/1475134/copy-all-metadata-file-and-video-and-non-video-streams-from-one-video-to-anoth)

Comment: For ignoring the video, add the argument `-vn` before the `-i` of the relevant input file. What do you mean "first video stream"?

Comment: pretty sure `ffmpeg` accepts negative selection. ie `!$` Not sure what it would do if you did not specify `v:` and just went with `c: a` or `a: copy` whatever the syntax is now. The other option that comes to mind is a `-map v` but I'm not familiar enough to advise.